# React provider component remounts after context change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I've made myself a simple theme provider as well as useTheme hook.

```
const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('base');

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={[theme, setTheme]}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useTheme = () => {
  const [themeName, setTheme] = useContext(ThemeContext);
  console.log(themeName);
  const theme = themes[themeName] || themes['base'];

  return { theme, themeName, setTheme };
};
```

`themes` is just an object with themes in it. I've wrapped `Component` in _app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

And made a simple page with a button to change theme

```
const Home = () => {
  const { themeName, setTheme } = useTheme();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        if (themeName === 'base') setTheme('dark');
        else setTheme('base');
      }}
    >
      button
    </button>
  );
};
```

When I first run the app console prints `base` (see the console.log in useTheme hook). But when I click the button console prints `dark` and `base` again. So everytime I change the context using `setTheme` function from `useTheme` hook ThemeProvider component unmounts and mounts again hence resetting its inner theme state back to `base`. Why is this happening?

Edit:
Entire _app.js file

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '@redux/store';
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'src/theme';

import '@styles/global.scss';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

Comment: Logging in function component body doesn't mean it unmounts, use `useEffect` for that. Aside from that please provide full reproducible example in a sandbox, we can't guess and where you mounting `MyApp` component

Comment: @DennisVash I used useEffect's return as well to see if it unmounts and it does. Also you can know where I'm mounting MyApp component I've mentioned it on OP, it's in _app.js. This is next.js project.

Comment: Again, pls show the app.js, your question isn't a reproducible example, its heavily depends on how u mount it, meaning, how do u pass it to your Component prop.

Comment: My guess there the mistake is in how you passing the Home component to MyApp

Comment: <Component {...pageProps} /> is the Home. Again this is a next.js project, Home is a page component. That is the entire app.js code except for imports and export. I do not see how it is relevant to see imports but I've added it to the OP.

Comment: Cant see the problem, you can make nextjs codesandbox for further help